# Array of Type calling a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method with the following signature:

```
Broker.GetMessages<TType>();
```

It can be used in the following way:

```
IList<IEmailMessage> emails = Broker.GetMessages<IEmailMessage>();
```

I need to execute this method for a series of types available within an array of this structure:

```
var messageTypes = new [] { typeof(IEmailMessage), typeof(IFaxMessage) }
```

My final result should be something like this:

```
foreach ( IMessage message in messageTypes)
{
   Broker.GetMessages<xxx>();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to covert the Type in order to pass it as a generic. I know I can use reflection to invoke the method but I was wondering if there is any better way to accomplish this.
I can change the array structure but not the method signature.

Comment: Your last code statement is actually foreach(Type message in messageTypes). Anyway, for this what you want to do, I would not chose a generic method but rather a regular method having (Type messageType) as input argument.

Comment: This method's signature should probably be more like `Broker.GetMessages(Type messageType);`. I bet you are calling `typeof(TType)` inside that method, which indicates it shouldn't be generic at all.

Comment: You didn't read the post at all. I can't change the signature of the broker because it's a third party assembly ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you would need to use reflection. You're half way there already given that you've got a `Type[]` - any time you use `typeof`, you're heading down the road to reflection. Generics are geared towards cases where you know the types at compile-time - and although you've hard-coded those types into your `messageTypes` array, you're still disconnecting the compile-time knowledge of the types from the invocation of the method.

It's fairly straightforward to do this:

```
var definition = typeof(Broker).GetMethod("GetMessages");
var generic = definition.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var result = generic.Invoke(null);
```

Comment: I though calling the makeGenericMethod was expensive because it is using reflection. If it's not that's the way I will make it working

Comment: @Raffaeu: I don't know how expensive it is, but you should get code which *works* first, and then check the cost. You could cache the result of `MakeGenericMethod` by type if you really wanted to, but I wouldn't add that complexity until I'd got *data* to show that it was required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to get my test fitness working and then see how expensive it is